# Is there any way to return a value from a block in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

As I said in title, is there any way to return a value from a block?

This is `PDDokdo` class

```c
@implementation PDDokdo
-(NSString *)getCurrentTemperature {
    WeatherPreferences * weatherPrefs = [NSClassFromString(@"WeatherPreferences") sharedPreferences];
    WATodayAutoupdatingLocationModel *todayModel = [[NSClassFromString(@"WATodayAutoupdatingLocationModel") alloc] init];
    [todayModel setPreferences:weatherPrefs];
    City *city = todayModel.forecastModel.city;

    __block double temp = 0;
    __block long long conditionCode = 0;
    [[NSClassFromString(@"TWCLocationUpdater") sharedLocationUpdater] updateWeatherForLocation:city.location city:city isFromFrameworkClient:true withCompletionHandler:^{
        temp = [[city temperature] celsius];
        conditionCode = [city conditionCode];

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f°C", round(temp)];
    }];

    return @":(";
}
@end
```

I want it to return a value in a block, not the end of the method.

Since `PDDokdo` is a sub-class of `NSObject`, I get the result like below in another class.

```c
NSString *temperature = [[PDDokdo alloc] getCurrentTemperature];
```

To sum up, I want `-(NSString *)getCurrentTemperature` to return `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f°C", round(temp)]` in a block instead of `:(`, so that I can get the value from another class.

Comment: It's async, right? You could use a semaphore for instance, or manage correctly and make the method with a block instead because it's async.

Comment: Pass the block as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCurrentTemperature` should return `void` and accept a block as a parameter:

```
typedef void(^CurrentTemperatureCompletion)(NSString *);

@implementation PDDokdo
-(void)getCurrentTemperature:(CurrentTemperatureCompletion)completion {
    WeatherPreferences * weatherPrefs = [NSClassFromString(@"WeatherPreferences") sharedPreferences];
    WATodayAutoupdatingLocationModel *todayModel = [[NSClassFromString(@"WATodayAutoupdatingLocationModel") alloc] init];
    [todayModel setPreferences:weatherPrefs];
    City *city = todayModel.forecastModel.city;

    __block double temp = 0;
    __block long long conditionCode = 0;
    [[NSClassFromString(@"TWCLocationUpdater") sharedLocationUpdater] updateWeatherForLocation:city.location city:city isFromFrameworkClient:true withCompletionHandler:^{
        temp = [[city temperature] celsius];
        conditionCode = [city conditionCode];

        NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f°C", round(temp)];
        completion(result);
        return result;
    }];
}
@end
```

In such case you don't need to wait for `updateWeatherForLocation` to complete.

This is how you can call it:

```
[[[PDDokdo alloc] init] getCurrentTemperature:^(NSString * temperature) {
    NSLog(@"%@", temperature);
}];
```